# Проблема с установкой PostgreSQL в Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql, debian, apt-get

Debian 8. Установил PostgreSQL, но при входе в `psql` от имени пользователя postgres какую-то проблему выдавало, связанное с сокетами. Гугл не помог (в проблеме я не одинок, но их гайды не помогли). Но не это важно.

Я решил удалить `sudo apt remove postgresql` (чтобы потом переустановить). Но ничего не изменилось. Пользователь postgres оставался, директория на /etc/postgresql оставалась. Удалил её. Плюс ещё значился в демонах `sudo service --status-all`. Удалил и её. И на init.d сохранялся. И там. Удалил. А при обратной установке выдаёт такое:

```
~$ sudo apt install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/52.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 57.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql.
(Reading database ... 59724 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql_9.4+165+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (9.4+165+deb8u2) ...
Setting up postgresql (9.4+165+deb8u2) ...
```

Естественно нет ни папки в etc, ни юзера postgres, ни демона, ничего!.

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install postgresql-9.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,663 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 59727 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-9.4_9.4.12-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-9.4 (9.4.12-0+deb8u1) over (9.4.12-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for postgresql-common (165+deb8u2) ...
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Setting up postgresql-9.4 (9.4.12-0+deb8u1) ...
```

ттт

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgresql-9.4
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc oidentd ident-server locales-all
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql postgresql-9.4
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,715 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-9.4.
(Reading database ... 59327 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-9.4_9.4.12-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-9.4 (9.4.12-0+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql_9.4+165+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (9.4+165+deb8u2) ...
Processing triggers for postgresql-common (165+deb8u2) ...
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Setting up postgresql-9.4 (9.4.12-0+deb8u1) ...
Use of uninitialized value $owneruid in getpwuid at /usr/bin/pg_createcluster line 280.
Error: clusters must not be owned by root
Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with

  pg_createcluster 9.4 main --start

or a similar command (see 'man pg_createcluster').
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.4/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
Setting up postgresql (9.4+165+deb8u2) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было установить сначала `postgresql-common`, а потом `postgresql-9.4`.

Answer (score 2):

в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах пакет *postgresql* — это мета-пакет, сам сервер распространяется в пакете, который указан в списке зависимостей пакета *postgresql*.

пример, как посмотреть зависимости пакета:

```
$ apt-cache depends postgresql
postgresql
  Depends: postgresql-9.4
  Suggests: postgresql-doc
```

в вашей версии дистрибутива версия, указанная в имени пакета, может быть другой (например, `postgresql-9.5`).

именно этот пакет (`postgresql-версия`) вам и надо было удалять, если вы хотели удалить сервер баз данных *postgresql*.

сейчас пакет с сервером у вас установлен, но вы вручную поудаляли часть файлов этого пакета. теперь вам надо его переустановить:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install postgresql-версия
```

---

другой способ посмотреть цифры версии:

```
$ dpkg --get-selecitons | grep postgresql
```

---

#### обновление.

переустановка может не помочь восстановить удалённые вручную конфигурационные файлы/каталоги.

тогда стоит попробовать переконфигурировать пакет явно:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure postgresql-версия
```

если и это не восстановит удалённые конфигурационные файлы/каталоги, имеет смысл сделать purge для этого пакета и install заново:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge postgresql-версия
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-версия
```

#### обновление2.

> ```
> Use of uninitialized value $owneruid in getpwuid at /usr/bin/pg_createcluster line 280.
> Error: clusters must not be owned by root
> Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with
>
>  pg_createcluster 9.4 main --start
> ```

отстутствует пользователь `postgres`. насколько я вижу, создаётся он пост-инсталляционным скриптом пакета `postgresql-common`. с ним надо проделать ту же операцию, что и с пакетом `postgresql-версия`:

1. для начала попробуйте переустановить:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get --reinstall install postgresql-common
   ```
2. если это не поможет, переконфигурируйте:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure postgresql-common
   ```
3. если и это не поможет:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get purge postgresql-common
   $ sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
   ```

Comment: См. описание выше. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Сделал как сказано. См. выше ответ консоли.

Comment: @SadrutdinZaynukov, обновил ответ.